# Hosted MySQL Server. Access Denied for user@localhost

Tags: mysql

I can't access my MySQL server from anywhere except from the hosted site itself.  The problem is I can't `GRANT PRIVILEGES` because I can't be the root user because it's just hosted is there any tweak for this?

Comment: How can you access the database?  How are you trying to access it?  Can you ask your hosting provider to fix the permissions?

Comment: id ask and also i joined to there forum and reported this. But they dont reply!

Comment: Do they have any other type of support other than a forum?

Comment: no. Email and Forum i think to make it clear i've hosted my site to 000webhost.com which i posted this permission issue to there customer assistance.

Comment: So, what do you mean by "except from the hosted site itself"?  How are you accessing the database?

Comment: It is best practice to restrict MySQL to localhost only.  It is probably normal that you get an `Access Denied` if you are trying to access MySQL with something else than PhpMyAdmin or a hosted PHP script.

Comment: usually that is the best way. too easy to hack into their system if they open up port 3307 for anybody

Comment: well i created a database using phpmyadmin and tested the simple php script and then it went ok inserting and echo the result. but then i created a PerlApp that connects to the MySQL server and then when the perl connecting to the MySQL it gave me this Access Denied For User@MYIP.

Comment: 'IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server Connection shows me this when i tried to connect to my website not to there given MySQL host